Excluding data from DTM using ArcMap
I am using ArcGIS 10.8.2 and I would like to estimate the least cost path between points.
I am using a DTM with two lakes and I would exclude these from the least cost path estimation.
I made some proofs generating the slope from the DTM, using the path distance tool with the vertical factor (Tobler’s hiking function) and then using the cost path tool to obtain the network path.
The result took into consideration the lakes passing partially through them.
I would exclude the two water basins from the estimation, thus considering just the territory.
To do that, I convert the poly to raster with the extent of the DTM.
Then, I reclassify the raster putting “no data” in all fields “new values”. The reclassified raster doesn’t appear in the environment.
Anyway, I open the raster calculator and multiply the new lake raster and the DTM.
The result doesn’t appear in the GIS environment and in the panel the raster shows odd values with minus and plus.
I attached the screenshots of the reclassify tool (the values 1 and 2 are substituted by "NoData) and the panel with the results of the reclassify and raster calculator tools.
Can you help me?

enter image description here

Old values 25 and 42 are the lake areas?  If so, New Value 1 and 2 should both be NoData and old value Nodata should be given a value of 1.
